# React Native. How to render dynamic catalog's menu (React navigation)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, catalog

Lets imagine, that we have **some catalog**, let it be the **goods catalog**.
**You have** **top level categories** **and** many **subcategories** for them and so on deeper. The whole **menu** can be **of any deep**.

[image]

Of course I **don't want to hardcode** this catalog, **I want to** **load** its structure **from a** remote server (**REST API** for instance), so that I could change it any time wothout posting changes to apps (App Store and Play Market). I am using **React-navigation** (if it makes any sense). *How it is usually done?*

***(1)*** Should I somehow create one page and pass there some parameters, or **(2)** should I create many distinct pages.

- In the first case **(1)** I can't even imagine, how can I pass new
  parameters to the same page again and again in such a way that each time
  there would be a new title in header of this page and a new submenu
  structure to be displayed.
- The second way **(2)** seems rather complex to me and is not the best
  idea... I suppose.

***What are best practices?***